# str is not callable の原因が分からない

Tags: python, python3

"WUB"という文字列をスペースに変えて、解読を行うというプログラムなのですが、

```
song = "AWUBWUBWUBBWUBWUBWUBC"
numbers = [int(i) for i in range(len(song))]
spaces = []
words = []
for i in range(len(song)-3):
  one, two, three = song[i], song[i+1], song[i+2]
  if one == "W" and two == "U" and three == "B":
    numbers.pop(i)
    numbers.pop(i+1)
    numbers.pop(i+2)
    spaces.append(i)
    i += 3
  else:
    i+=1
  for i in range(len(numbers)):
    words.append(song(numbers[i]))
  for k in range(len(spaces)):
    words.insert(spaces[k], " ")
ans = ''.join(words)
print(ans)
```

としたところ、

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-cc5ee7fdeeb7> in <module>()
     14     i+=1
     15   for i in range(len(numbers)):
---> 16     words.append(song(numbers[i]))
     17   for k in range(len(spaces)):
     18     words.insert(spaces[k], " ")

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

となってしまいます。
intにしているつもりなのですが、どこでstrにすり替わってしまっているのか教えていただけると幸いです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

直接的には`words.append(song(numbers[i]))`という行が、`song(numbers[i])`という関数があって呼ばれているように見えるが、そんなものは無いのでエラーになっているということです。

`song`は文字列なので、それと`numbers[i]`との関係が、本当は何をしようと考えていたか？ で修正内容が変わってくるでしょう。

---

コメント対応：

単純には`( )`を`[ ]`に変えることで、`song`から1文字づつ`words`に追加する処理に出来ます。

```
words.append(song[numbers[i]])
```

しかしそれをすると、今度は4回目に実行された`numbers.pop(i+1)`の行で`IndexError: pop index out of range`になります。
この時`i`は11で、`numbers`は [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 19, 20] でした。`i+1`が12なのでリストの要素数の範囲外ですね。

だからまだまだプログラムは未完成状態でしょう。

Comment: numbersはintの集合のリストとして作ったつもりなので、そのリストの特定の要素(int)を取り出し、そのintを引数としてsongという文字列のリストから文字をコピーし、wordという空のリストにappendしようと思っていました。どうすれば以上のコマンドをコードで表現できるのかもしご存知でしたら教えていただけると幸いです。